# What is the difference between Android webview's loadData and loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android, methods, webview, load

The Android webview has 2 methods to load data

```
public void loadData (String data, String mimeType, String encoding)
```

> Note that JavaScript's same origin policy means that script running in
>   a page loaded using this method will be unable to access content
>   loaded using any scheme other than 'data', including 'http(s)'. To
>   avoid this restriction, use loadDataWithBaseURL() with an appropriate
>   base URL.

and

```
public void loadDataWithBaseURL (String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)
```

> Note that content specified in this way can access local device files
>   (via 'file' scheme URLs) only if baseUrl specifies a scheme other than
>   'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'about' or 'javascript'.

I don't know what do these 2 sentences mean and when to select between the two ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've been wondering, how does `setWebViewClient` compare??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public void loadData (String data, String mimeType, String encoding)
```

In this we pass  the HTML, mimeType and encoding

where else in

```
public void loadDataWithBaseURL (String baseUrl, String data, String mimeType, String encoding, String historyUrl)
```

where baseUrl could be the base url such as the path to asset folder, or SDCard or any other path, where your images or the other media resides related to your html, and I am not much aware of historyUrl

accoring to the docs of `[loadData][1]`

> Note that JavaScript's same origin policy means that script running in a page loaded using this method will be unable to access content loaded using any scheme other than 'data', including 'http(s)'. To avoid this restriction, use `loadDataWithBaseURL()` with an appropriate base URL.

means `loaddata` will only include the part which is resides in the first parameter.

and

> Note that content specified in this way can access local device files (via 'file' scheme URLs) only if baseUrl specifies a scheme other than 'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'about' or 'javascript'.

simple meaning of above is you can access the data from http and... other by passing the baseUrl

**for example** I have written HTML which required tons of image from my ftp or other place what I would do is pass the url of my ftp in baseURl parameter and I can access to my images

Comment: @Yama moto consider this... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme, which mentioned:- used to retrieve files from within one's own computer. in our case it is phone

Comment: what does scheme mean in this context ?

Comment: please go through the link it will be helpful

Comment: Does this mean using null for base url will allow me to access javascript from different domain ?

Comment: when I pass in the baseURL the path to the location of the file on the device (file://...) the webview accesses the content beautifully but is no longer responsive to any link or anchor in the file. kindly take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165203/using-loaddatawithbaseurl-disables-links-in-webview

Answer (score 4):

The second one comes in handy when you're loading the HTML locally and it references assets such as images & css which are also packaged locally

Answer (score 1):

loadDataWithBaseURL() also comes with Unicode support. It might be helpful when you are trying to load the webpage with content other than English Language.